# Autofill selected cells in VBA but ignore those who have no values in Row 2

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to autofill cells in VBA using the value of last row however I do not want to autofill if row 2 is empty. Please see the example below: Row 1 contain column names and data starts from row 2

Original Table

| Fruits | Colors | Shape | Taste |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Red |  | Sweet |
|  | Green |  | Sour |
|  | Yellow |  | Sweet |
| Orange | Orange |  | Sour |
|  | Red |  |  |

What I would like

| Fruits | Colors | Shape | Taste |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Red |  | Sweet |
| Apples | Green |  | Sour |
| Apples | Yellow |  | Sweet |
| Orange | Orange |  | Sour |
| Orange | Red |  | Sour |

I am using the code below but it is giving me the following result, I don't want **Shape** to be autofilled as well

```
Sub FillDownBlanks()
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell = "" Then
            cell.FillDown
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

| Fruits | Colors | Shape | Taste |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apples | Red | Shape | Sweet |
| Apples | Green | Shape | Sour |
| Apples | Yellow | Shape | Sweet |
| Orange | Orange | Shape | Sour |
| Orange | Red | Shape | Sour |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try.

```
Sub FillDownBlanks()
    For Each cell In Selection
        If cell = "" And Cells(2, cell.Column) <> "" Then
            cell.FillDown
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

If there are lots of cells in selection, you could remove the unwanted columns before looping through cells.

```vb
Sub FillDownBlanksOpt()
    Dim rngFill As Range, col As Range, cell As Range
    For Each col In Selection.Columns
        ' cells(2) is the cell on the 2nd row of selection
        If col.Cells(2) <> "" Then
            If rngFill Is Nothing Then
                Set rngFill = col
            Else
                Set rngFill = Union(rngFill, col)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If Not rngFill Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In rngFill.Cells
            If cell = "" Then
                cell.FillDown
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

> [Range.FillDown method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)